# Calculating dimensions of STL (stereolithography) object from .stl files

Tags: dimensions

How can I get the length,width and height of 3D object stored as a .stl file?

Comment: I need to knwo that as well, How do you host STL file in WPF ?

Answer (score 1):

STL files are dimensionless, so whatever is reading the stl must know what units the file was written in.

The format of stl files is [detailed in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29)